# How can I get the remote address from an incoming message on UDP listener socket?

Tags: sockets, udp, gio, gjs

Although it's possible to read from a `Gio.Socket` by wrapping it's file-descriptor in `Gio.DataInputStream`, using `Gio.Socket.receive_from()` **in GJS** to receive is not possible because as [commented here](https://gist.github.com/maghul/4ddaa5879ef0ece5dbe3):

> **GJS will clone array arguments before passing them to the C-code** which will make the call to Socket.receive_from work and return the number of bytes received as well as the source of the packet. The buffer content will be unchanged as **buffer actually read into is a freed clone**.

Thus, input arguments are cloned and data will be written to the *cloned* buffer, not the instance of `buffer` actually passed in.

Although reading from a data stream is not a problem, `Gio.Socket.receive_from()` is the only way I can find to get the remote address from a UDP listener, since `Gio.Socket.remote_address` will be undefined. Unfortunately as the docs say for `Gio.Socket.receive()`:

> For `G_SOCKET_TYPE_DATAGRAM` [...] If the received message is too large to fit in `buffer`, then the data beyond `size` bytes will be discarded, without any explicit indication that this has occurred.

So if I try something like `Gio.Socket.receive_from(new Uint8Array(0), null);` just to get the address, the packet is swallowed, but if I read via the file-descriptor I can't tell where the message came from. Is there another non-destructive way to get the incoming address for a packet?

Comment: Why doe cloning the datagram prevent you from obtaining its source?

Comment: Sorry, the comment I quoted is not entirely clear. Getting the address is possible with `Gio.Source.receive_from(buffer, cancellable)` (in GJS this returns an array of `[size, address]`), but because GJS clones the args passed in the `buffer` will have no data written to it. So passing a `Uint8Array(4096)` will result in `buffer` being filled with 4k of null bytes, since the data is being written to the cloned arg, not the original.

Comment: I clarified my question somewhat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you’re using a datagram socket, it should be possible to use [`Gio.Socket.receive_message()`](https://people.gnome.org/~gcampagna/docs/Gio-2.0/Gio.Socket.receive_message.html) and pass the `Gio.SocketMsgFlags.PEEK` flag to it. This isn’t possible for a stream-based socket, but you are not going to want the sender address for each read you do in that case.

If you want improved performance, you may be able to use `Gio.Socket.receive_messages()`, although I am not sure whether that’s completely introspectable at the moment.

Comment: Excellent, that does it! I had almost given up hope on this one.